# Bluetooth headset is paired but cant stream music

Tags: windows-7, audio, 64-bit, bluetooth, headset

I want to play music with bluetooth with my headset.
 - My headset is working on my Android devices.
 - No driver error on windows.
 - The headset seems to be connected.

The operation "List To Music" is disabled for some reason.

I have searched a lot on google and could not find the fix for my problem.

In the image you can see my device info:

[image]

My system is Windoe 7 SP1 64 bit.